# Deploying asp.net mvc app to folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a hosting running windows, lets say the root domain is xxx.com. On xxx.com there should be website running on php (since IIS can run PHP, right?) or asp.net. I really dont know yet.

I am now responsible of making a asp.net mvc app, which should be running only inside a folder like xxx.com/myaspapp.

I've tried to publish the app straight to the folder via visual studio and it fails with an error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file
>   required to service this request. Please review the specific error details 
>   below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as 
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error 
>   can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

What is a solution for this? Is this scenario even possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

WebDeploy can create a virtual application under an IIS site automatically.  Check it out:

[THE ANATOMY OF A WEBDEPLOY PACKAGE](https://dotnetcatch.com/2016/02/25/the-anatomy-of-a-webdeploy-package/)

Answer (score 0):

It is simple to host an application in a sub folder. Follow the below steps.

- Create a folder (myaspapp) under the root site path.
- Open IIS Manager (inetmgr) and expand till the new folder.
- Right the newly created folder and click on **Convert to Application**.
- Deploy/Upload the application files directly to this folder.

Now you will be able to access the site from the sub folder.

Comment: well, this hosting service doesn't allow me to modify IIS, I will try to solve it thru customer support. many thanks to you

Comment: So guys, thank you very much for your time. But the hosting provider had ton of excuses, how they cannot do this. So yes, solution is easy, but Czech hostings are very bad :)